# Integrating static website with wordpress one page blog

Tags: wordpress

SO I basically have created my website using the foundation theme. I have just been told by my boss that we need a blog page to be created using Wordpress. I have no problem in doing but I am a little confused on linking the blog page with the static website. Any advice on taking on this approach. I have done my research but seem to be getting information of just Wordpress in general

Comment: You can install WordPress in a subfolder (e.g. /blog). By default, the index of the install will show your latest blog posts.

Comment: So within my public_html folder in FIlezilla you want me to put the wordpress folder within there. I am wanting to know how to link the blog page with my normal navigation on my website

Comment: You'd create a `blog` directory in your `public_html` and then install WordPress in that folder. To link to it, you'd simply use a link tag in the following format: `<a href="/blog">Blog</a>`

Comment: Oh I understanding. SO within my static website in the navigation bar I would do the following 

       <section class="top-bar-section">
        <!-- Right Nav Section -->
        <ul class="right">
          <li><a href="faqs.html">FAQs</a></li>
           <li><a href="/blog">BLOG</a></li>
        </ul>
        </section>
     </nav>
    </div> <!--END OF STICKY-->
@rnevius